# MySQL: How to show rows/cells that does not contain the specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| PRIMARYKEY | NAME   | TYPE      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 0001       | Adam   | Import    |
| 0001       | Adam   | Transfer  |
| 0001       | Adam   | Payment   |
| 0002       | Brooke | Import    |
| 0002       | Brooke | Transfer  |
| 0003       | Chloe  | Import    |
| 0003       | Chloe  | Transfer  |
| 0003       | Chloe  | Payment   |
| 0004       | David  | Import    |
| 0004       | David  | Transfer  |
| 0005       | Emily  | Import    |
| 0005       | Emily  | Transfer  |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
  account.PRIMARYKEY,
  client.NAME,
  transaction.TYPE,
FROM
  account
    JOIN
  client ON account.ACCOUNTKEY = client.PRIMARYKEY
    JOIN
  transaction ON account.PRIMARYKEY = transaction.ACCOUNTKEY
```

I would like to get all the data that has no `Payment` and group it by `PRIMARYKEY` like so

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| PRIMARYKEY | NAME   | TYPE      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 0002       | Brooke | Import    |
| 0004       | David  | Import    |
| 0005       | Emily  | Import    |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

I've tried

```
WHERE
  transaction.TYPE NOT LIKE 'Payment'
```

But failed

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to use NOT IN instead of NOT LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. The inner query in the `WHERE` clause will get all accounts that has payments but since `NOT EXISTS` was used, it will exclude all accounts that is in the inner query.

```
SELECT  account.PRIMARYKEY,
        client.NAME,
        MIN(t.TYPE)
FROM    account
        JOIN client ON account.ACCOUNTKEY = client.PRIMARYKEY
        JOIN transaction t ON account.PRIMARYKEY = t.ACCOUNTKEY
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    transaction a
                        WHERE   a.ACCOUNTKEY = t.ACCOUNTKEY
                                AND a.Type = 'Payment'
                    )
GROUP   account.PRIMARYKEY,
        client.NAME
```

Here's a guide that shows the difference in [performance between IN, JOIN, EXISTS](https://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/).

Comment: Thank sir. You've help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using an [SQL `IN` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
SELECT 
  account.PRIMARYKEY,
  client.NAME,
  transaction.TYPE,
FROM
  account
    JOIN
  client ON account.ACCOUNTKEY = client.PRIMARYKEY
    JOIN
  transaction ON account.PRIMARYKEY = transaction.ACCOUNTKEY
WHERE NOT account.PRIMARYKEY IN (SELECT ACCOUNTKEY FROM transaction WHERE TYPE = 'Payment'))
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: @dhie, you are very welcome.  Please remember to **accept** one of the answers if the community have helped to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT PRIMARYKEY  ,
       NAME        ,
       TYPE
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE PRIMARYKEY NOT IN (SELECT PRIMARYKEY  
                            FROM YourTable
                           WHERE TYPE = 'Payment'
                         )
   AND TYPE = 'Import'
```

Comment: OP's code clearly shows he has 3 tables: `account`, `client`, and `transaction`.  That's why the JOIN is in there.

Comment: @Tersosauros, OP shows one table at the beginning of his question, never mind his query. If there are really 3 tables (as you claim), the essence of the proposed solution does not change a bit.

Comment: the first set of tabular data is the *result* of the query, as indicated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One minimally invasive approach here is to just join to an additional subquery which identifies accounts for which `payment` never appears as a type.  We do this an inner join, to filter off non matching accounts which we don't want.

```
SELECT 
    a.PRIMARYKEY,
    c.NAME,
    t1.TYPE
FROM account a
INNER JOIN client c
    ON a.ACCOUNTKEY = c.PRIMARYKEY
INNER JOIN transaction t1
    ON a.PRIMARYKEY = t1.ACCOUNTKEY
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ACCOUNTKEY
    FROM transaction
    GROUP BY ACCOUNTKEY
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'payment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON a.PRIMARYKEY = t2.ACCOUNTKEY;
```